# How to use variable inside a word

Tags: powershell

I have a list of documents with names *Windows2008Single.pdf*, *Windows2012Single.pdf* and *Windows2016Single.pdf*.

I want to replace `2008`/`2012`/`2016` with input variable:

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Which Server do you want to read: 2008 2012 2016'
```

Then open the pdf file:

```
Start-Process ((Resolve-path "C:\xxx\xxx\Win($Server)Single.pdf").Path)
```

But I can't get it work, if I don't use `()`, then it think `$ServerSingle` is a variable name, if I use `()`, then output will be *Windows(2008)Single.pdf* and it can't find the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `{}` to help powershell understand where variable name ends in such cases.

```
"Win${Server}Single.pdf"
```

Comment: in that case you should accept this answer as valid to help community ;) @Jasmine

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your variable in `$()` like so:

```
Start-Process ((Resolve-path "C:\xxx\xxx\Win$($Server)Single.pdf").Path)
```